# LDAP Query originating from client-side "onload"

Tags: javascript, php, html, .net, active-directory

I have asked previous questions but I think I got too far into pre-conceived notions that I ruled out other options.  I'm going to start over:

I have tools which are developed and maintained in HTML and JavaScript.  What I would like to do is automate the collection of user data.  The users are currently filling in their information and we are storing them in cookies for 6 months.  However, If I can have them skip the step of manually inputting this information it'll be a small time savings.

If I'm going to be using something server-side I'll be using Microsoft Web Server 2012 with IIS 8.5.

What I would like to know is:  What is the best approach in terms of language?

Is the best approach a client AJAX call to ASP.Net page which writes the user data back into JSON format?  Should I try authenticated queries or non-authenticated queries?  I'm lost.

I need recommendations and some guidance with where and how to get started/what I need to learn.

**Update:**  To be clear, I'm looking for a solution that will be external to my existing code.  Something that I can access externally (e.g. AJAX comes to mind) and have it spit back (AD data point indicators):  givenName, sn, displayName, telephoneNumber, title.

Comment: You are attempting to have users log in using their LDAP credentials from client side?

Comment: Maybe?  I should state that I'm not the server admin nor have I ever been one... so I'm a noob. I just read [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/329986/how-to-use-the-system.directoryservices-namespace-in-asp.net) regarding how to collect user authentication and pass it over to the LDAP.  The tools that I'm using are currently being housed in SharePoint 2010 and will be migrated over to SP2016 soon.  The only way that I would know how to pass a user's username/password would be in the query string... and that's just unsafe.... so I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple layers to this. I order to securely pass data between the client and server, you need to use HTTPS. You can buy a certificate from several websites, but for development lets create a self-signed certificate. In IIS, go to server>Server Certificates>Create Self-Signed Certificate..., enter a name and click on OK.

Now we need to use that certificate. Go to Sites>Add Web Site..., give it a site name, a physical path, in the Binding section, set Type to https, and select the certificate we made in SSL Certificates. Click OK.

If you don't have visual studio, get the express version from https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/. Once installed, open Visual Studio. Go to File>New Website..., choose Visual C#>ASP.NET Web Site, and click OK.

In the Solution Explorer, expand Account and double click on Login.aspx. In the main panel, click on Split to get a view of the HTML and what it will render like. Click on the Log In button. In the Properties panel, click on the lightning bolt to get to actions and double click in the Click option.

In here, we will use DirectoryServices, which needs to be referenced in your project. Right click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Add Reference.... In the .NET tab, select System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, and click OK. Now in Account/Login.aspx.cs in LoginButton_Click enter:

```
bool validUser;
    PrincipalContext ctx  = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    validUser = ctx.ValidateCredentials(this.LoginUser.UserName, this.LoginUser.Password);
    if (validUser) {
        // Do you stuff here.
    }
```

You now have the very basic LDAP enabled website.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, you are collecting the users data when they visit this page right?.........If that's the case, then I can't  use this solution.  I'm looking for a solution that I can access externally (e.g. AJAX) where it would run the query server-side and then spit back the data that I could have sent back to the client.  My reason?  If I did what you're talking about, I'd have to change all of my HTML files to .ASPX files.  I just can't do that.

Comment: .NET web applications do not run client-side. There is a compiled file on the IIS server and the .aspx file is used as a template to present to the user. There is AJAX code generated for you to handle viewstate and whatnot. When the user clicks on the login button, there is a POST to the server with the username/password and the session information is handled there.